# How would one pass an interface as a generic type and use it as an annotation?

Tags: java, generics, annotations

Let's say I've got an annotation interface of `foo`

```
@interface foo {
    String bar();
}
```

I want to be able to pass `foo` to a generic `T` in a class, let's call it `someClass`

```
class someClass<T> {
    T ourAnnotation = getClass().getAnnotation(T); // this won't work
}
```

The reason I'd pass this is that later on, when creating a base class, we can pass this generic

```
@foo(bar = ...)
public class MyClass extends someClass<foo> {
    public MyClass() {
        ourAnnotation.bar // ... do stuff
    }
}
```

How would I be able to pass this?

Edit: I've figured out a solution

Within `someClass`, I've made the following modifications:

```
class someClass<T> {
    final T info;
    public someClass(Class<T> tClass) {
        info = getClass().getAnnotation(tClass);
    }
}
```

Then, by passing `foo` (make sure it's retention policy is set to runtime), you can easily grab the values from `MyClass`.

Comment: The duplicate explains how to get the type `T`'s corresponding `Class` object for a subclass of `someClass`. You can then pass that to `getAnnotation`.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Within `someClass`, I've made the following modifications:

```
class someClass<T> {
    final T info;
    public someClass(Class<T> tClass) {
        info = getClass().getAnnotation(tClass);
    }
}
```

Then, by passing `foo` (make sure it's retention policy is set to runtime), you can easily grab the values from `MyClass`.

This allows gson to find the values